# how to create menu like kijiji's main page with html and jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, menu

I have a requirement that I need to create location selector just like kijiji.ca

If I select the province then the cities in that province will be displayed just like www.kijiji.ca main page (location selector)

They have use ul s and li s to create the menu with ajax support.

I know the ajax part but having trouble with formatting the menu and how to make cities appear on selection of province and at the very same vertical position as the province.

Below is the html for province and city ul s.

```
   <div class="location-wrapper">
        <ul class="locMenu drop-down level-1">
            <li data-loc-id="9003" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Alberta</a></li><li
                data-loc-id="9007" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">British Columbia</a></li><li
                    data-loc-id="9006" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Manitoba</a></li><li
                        data-loc-id="9005" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">New Brunswick</a></li><li
                            data-loc-id="9008" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Newfoundland</a></li><li
                                data-loc-id="9002" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Nova Scotia</a></li><li
                                    data-loc-id="9004" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Ontario (A - L)</a></li><li
                                        data-loc-id="100009004" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Ontario (M - Z)</a></li><li
                                            data-loc-id="9011" class="more selected"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Prince Edward
                                                Island</a></li><li data-loc-id="9001" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Québec</a></li><li
                                                    data-loc-id="9009" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Saskatchewan</a></li><li
                                                        data-loc-id="9010" class="more"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Territories</a></li></ul>
        <ul class="locMenu drop-down level-2" style="margin-top: 168px;">
            <li data-loc-id="1700118" class="more children"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Prince
                Edward Island</a></li></ul>
        <ul class="locMenu drop-down level-3" style="margin-top: 168px;">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

You can check out the website at www.kijiji.ca first page

Comment: Why don't you just hire someone who knows how to program in jQuery to do it for you?  B/c I'm not, and doubt anyone else will.

Comment: I already have done it. I just need to know the best solution. If you have any idea then please contribute. It will be constructive for others as well

Comment: Post the code with what you've done, because the HTML in your question isn't all of it.  Also, what's *the best solution* supposed to mean? Does it work? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was simple I just had to play with

```
margin-top:
```

property

And use show and hide of jquery

Data was coming from server so I just had to use either pagemethods or jquery ajax.

Simple